# Curve fitting data to model

Tags: fitting

**Example**

Assumptions:

```
ClearAll[m, F, b, \[Omega], \[Delta]]
$Assumptions = x > 0 && m > 0 && F > 0 && b > 0 && \[Omega] > 0 && \[Delta] > 0;
```

In the following, $m$ is the mass of the mechanical system and $\delta$ is the phaseshift of the system.

```
m = 0.17869 + 0.01376/3;
\[Delta] = ArcTan[b/(m*(\[Omega]^2 - x^2))*x];
```

The experimental data:

```
data = {{0.7123448644,0.00246},{0.7324185582,0.00266},{0.7861292525,0.00328},{0.8523181889,0.00451},{0.9109116735,0.00647},{0.9282727060,0.00760},{0.9906639165,0.0114},{1.025928514,0.0152},{1.051970063,0.0222},{1.079096676,0.0131},{1.105138225,0.00865},{1.149625870,0.00549},{1.170242096,0.00455},{1.220155065,0.00336},{1.256504727,0.00267},{1.351990405,0.00184}};
```

The fitting function:

```
A[x_] := F/(m*\[Omega]^2*
     Sqrt[   (x - \[Delta])^4 
           + ((b/(m*\[Omega]))^2 - 2)*(x - \[Delta])^2 
           + 1])
```

where $F$, $b$, and $\omega$ are parameters connected to the system.

Determineing the missing parameters:

```
FindFit[data, A[x], {F, b, \[Omega]}, x]
```

> {F -> 0.00584067, b -> 0.972727, [Omega] -> -1.10514}

```
F = 0.005840667856395345;
b = 0.9727272619465833;
\[Omega] = -1.105138224999997;
```

Plot of data and the fitting curve:

```
Show[Plot[A[x], {x, 0.6, 1.5}, PlotRange -> Full], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

> [image: output]

It is obvious that the fitting is all wrong.

How do I get the correct fitting parameters?

I know that the fit should give approximately

```
F = 0.03
b = 0.14
\[Omega] = 12
```

P.S. I would think that executing the first command would assure that $\omega > 0$ when finding the fitting parameters, but this is obviously not the case.

Comment: There are not enough degrees of freedom in your model to accommodate this shift. Try with `Manipulate` to see what I mean.

Comment: @OleksandrR. So I can't get a correct fit with the data available?

Comment: Apparently not, unless you modify the model to incorporate that small shift. How best to do that while retaining its physical validity (looks like some resonant mechanical system?) will depend on how the measurements are done and so on, and we can't really help you with that for obvious reasons. If these are experimental data, is it possible for example that all readings of `x` are slightly shifted due to an instrumental effect? Or maybe they're subject to a multiplicative error...

Comment: @OleksandrR. I have updated my question. (It is indeed a mechanical system and one can get a phaseshift in order to horizontally correct the fitting function.)

Comment: @Nasser Can I make you write up an answer where the correct fit is obtained? (I have to go now and won't be back for the next 18-20 hours.)

Comment: have you tried supplying your approximate solution as a starting value to findfit?

Comment: Important :  FindFit does not use $Assumptions. You need to directly supply the constraints as an argument. See the docs for FindFit..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you haven't specified everything, here is one way to approach this:

```
a[x_] := F/(m*ω^2*Sqrt[(x - δ)^4 + ((b/(m*ω))^2 - 2)*(x - δ)^2 + 1]);
sol = NonlinearModelFit[data, a[x], 
   {{F, 0.03}, {b, 0.14}, {ω, 12}, {δ, 1}, {m, 0.17869 + 0.01376/3}}, x];
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[sol[x], {x, 0.7, 1.4}]]
```

[image]